# Nanosecond-resolution mtime/ctime/atime with Node's fs.stat

Tags: node.js, time, stat

The times returned by Node's `fs.stat` seem to have one-second resolution even on file systems that support nanosecond resolution, like ext4.

```
var fs = require('fs')
var stats = fs.statSync('.')
stats.mtime.getMilliseconds() // => always 0
```

How do I get stat times with better resolution? Nanoseconds would be ideal, but milliseconds or microseconds is OK too.

Comment: Long shot, but the source code has a suspicious /1000. Not sure if this is the culprit https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js#L854

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Node v8.10 millisecond and nanosecond resolution time is available as separate properties:

```
 stats.mtimeMs
 stats.ctimeMs
 stats.atimeMs
```

i.e.

```
stats.mtime.getMillieseconds() //546
stats.mtimeMs // 1391354639546.3066
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to upgrade Node. As of Node 0.11.0 ([#3284](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3284), [51f128d](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/51f128d64b250dfeb128aab5117b5bbcd2cc51b5)), we get millisecond-resolution time:

```
var fs = require('fs')
var stats = fs.statSync('.')
stats.mtime.getMilliseconds() // => 367
```

I'm still not sure if there's a way to get nanoseconds, but getting milliseconds is a big improvement.